# How to get all values inside HTML table using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, html-table

I have a table which looks like below and i want to get all values inside the table including the value of text box and check box.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<h1 class="h3 mb-4 text-gray-800"><?= $title; ?></h1>
<div class="container" style="text-align: left">
    <table class="table table-sm" id="tbl">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Checklist Item</th>
                <th>Cheklist</th>
                <th>Actual</th>
                <th>Recomended</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">1</td>
                <td>Check and clean rubber roller cage</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="chek" id="check"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">2</td>
                <td>Tension Rod all </td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="chek" id="check"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">3</td>
                <td>Delete all unnecessary file from system</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="chek" id="check"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-success" id="save">save</a>
</div>
```

when i grab all value using this script i cant get value inside the text box and checkbox

```
$(document).on('click', '#save', function() {
        var myRows = [];
        var headersText = [];
        var $headers = $("th");

        // Loop through grabbing everything
        var $rows = $("tbody tr").each(function(index) {
            $cells = $(this).find("td");
            myRows[index] = {};

            $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
                // Set the header text
                if (headersText[cellIndex] === undefined) {
                    headersText[cellIndex] = $($headers[cellIndex]).text();
                }
                // Update the row object with the header/cell combo
                myRows[index][headersText[cellIndex]] = $(this).text();
            });
        });

        var myObj = {
            "Array": myRows
        };
        alert(JSON.stringify(myObj));
    });
```

I want to convert it to JSON but the value of text box and check box not shows inside table. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you want to structure data for checkboxes ? Just return checked state?

Comment: yes return 1 or 0 depend on state

Comment: So similar to answer below use a more robust `if()` .... `if($(this).has(':checkbox')){ valueWanted = $(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked') ? 1 :0} else if(($(this).has(':text'){ valueWanted = $(this).find('input').val()} else{ /* get the text*/..`

Comment: can i get the complete code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the input and use `.val()` to get its value if the table cell's text is empty. Checkboxes and text inputs will need to be handled separately.

```
const text = $(this).text();
if(text){
   myRows[index][headersText[cellIndex]] = text;
} else {
   const input = $(this).find('input');
   if(input.is(":checkbox")){
      myRows[index][headersText[cellIndex]] = +input.prop('checked');
   } else {
      myRows[index][headersText[cellIndex]] = input.val();
   }
}
```

Comment: Going to need more granular handling for checkboxes

Comment: the code can get the value of text box but the chechbox only get "on" whatever checked or not.

Comment: @AzihiMafaza No problem.